# When to apply noise reduction? Before or after other processing?

Tags: post-production, noise-reduction

I have a recording, in which i will do some processing, specifically:

1. Expand
2. Boost a bit around 150hz

I also need to apply noise reduction

My question is: When noise reduction is applied? **Before** or **after** any other processing (in my case, like the expand and boost)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really depends. 
Sometimes you need a global volume boost because the audio is too low anyway to correctly listen to the noise reduction you're applying. Sometimes there's a 50 or 60Hz rumble or any other fixed unwanted frequency that you could remove before denoising...
But generally speaking "the sooner the better". And before any processing other than gain or subtractive EQ.

Answer (score 4):

It does depend but most will apply it early in the chain especially if it's an offline process like Izotope Denoiser.  It's much easier for the software to work if the noise floor isn't moving around and being compressed, expanded, clip gained, volume automation etc.

Answer (score 3):

Do some tests using all permutations and trust your ears. The more you take this experimental approach to your work the better idea you will have about which techniques suit which circumstances. Learning by experience will build your skills far better than just doing what you're told is 'the' answer.